# useState data not working with .map function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have this app that fetches the blog posts from an API. The API response with blog posts and I'm getting those blog posts to `GetBlogState` state. When I'm looping through `GetBlogState` using the .map I am getting the following error.

[image]

The following is the code that I'm currently working with.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head'
import axios from 'axios'
import HeaderComponent from '../components/HeaderComponent';

export default function Blog(){

  const [GetBlogState, SetBlogState] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:4000/blog').then(res => {
      SetBlogState(res)
    }).catch(errr => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="MyApp">
        { GetBlogState.map(item => (
        <div className="h-68">
            <img className="w-full" alt="post" src='post.jpg' />
            <div className="mt-3 mb-2 text-xs">May 10, 2018</div>
            <h2 className="font-bold mb-5 text-xl"><a href="/" className="hover:underline">{ item.Title } </a></h2>
            <p>{item.content}</p>
        </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Check `res` variable. It could to be an object, null, string… and only array has `map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should check the output what you are getting in res from axios.

you are setting response object in state which is wrong.

You should do

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:4000/blog').then(res => {
    //// console.log(res) Check whats returning in res \\\
       SetBlogState(res.data)
    }).catch(errr => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }, []);
```

Comment: I feel so stupid right now for overlooking such a small thing. Thanks. It's working now.

Comment: @RedVirus no worries. Whenever you using anything in programming. First read the documentation. It will help you alot.

Answer (score 1):

Axios' response schema put server response in `data`. Hence set state like `SetBlogState(res.data)`